# How to Keep Bootstrap Dropdown Open with Select

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap dropdown with a select box which has a few options that I want there. It looks fine until I click on it, the drop-down closes. How can I keep the drop-down open if I click on the select box?

[Here's a bootply.](https://www.bootply.com/95FU2GksH4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `onclick="event.stopPropagation();"` to your `<select>`

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Menu
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Choice1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Choice2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Choice3</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <select onclick="event.stopPropagation();">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need 2 changes...

1. add .dropdown class to the .btn-group
2. wrap the select in a `<form>`

https://www.bootply.com/4lwQ9hCY7k

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown">
  <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Menu
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Choice1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Choice2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Choice3</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <form>
      <select>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </form>  
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version without js, but may have some inconveniences:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#list">
    Menu
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>

  <ul id="list" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Choice1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Choice2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Choice3</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <select>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
   </ul>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://www.bootply.com/vSR9Dt4xn2)